# How to make Volley NetworkImageView worke offline

Tags: android, android-volley

I use `Volley NetworkImageView` to download images from internet and show in my `listview`. Now I want to make `Volley NetworkImageView` show saved images when there is no network available. `Volley` has already cached images by `URL` as a key because when I use

```
Entry entry = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().getCache().get(imageURL);
```

the `entry.data` is not null. But my problem is that image resolutions are high and I can not use

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entry.data, 0, entry.data.length);
```

because it creates a lot of lag and I have to reinvent the wheel because again I must create `asynctask` see when `listview` has scrolled to cancel decoding, recycling the `bitmap`, creating in memory cache, finding best insample value and ...

so better Idea is just do some tricks that make `Volley NetworkImageView` **use its own DiskLRUCache** to show them when there is no network.

Any idea?

My code:

```
public class SingletonRequestQueue {


    private static SingletonRequestQueue mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private SingletonRequestQueue(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
        mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache(LruBitmapCache.getCacheSize(context));
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,mLruBitmapCache);

    }

    public static synchronized SingletonRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SingletonRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {

            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.

            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext(),new OkHttpStack());
//          mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    } 

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        return mLruBitmapCache;
    }

    public void setLruBitmapCache(LruBitmapCache lruBitmapCache) {
        mLruBitmapCache = lruBitmapCache;
    }


}
```

and in my adapter:

```
public IssueListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Issue> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mIssueList = objects;
        mImageLoader = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
}

public static class ViewHolder{

    public  NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
    public  TextView mFee;
    public  TextView mName;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater =    
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_issuelist_item, parent, false);

        holder.mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.NetworkImageView_MainActivity_issue_image);
        holder.mName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_MainActivity_name);
        holder.mFee = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_MainActivity_fee);
        Utility.settingTypfaceFont(context, holder.mName);
        Utility.settingTypfaceFont(context, holder.mFee);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)(convertView.getTag());
    }

    final Issue issue = mIssueList.get(position);
    holder.mName.setText(issue.getTitle());
    holder.mFee.setText(String.valueOf(issue.getFee()));
    String imageURL = issue.getPublicCover();

    holder.mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(imageURL, mImageLoader);
    holder.mNetworkImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.placeholder2);;

    /*
    Entry entry = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().getCache().get(imageURL);
    if(entry != null && entry.data != null){
        byte[] imageByte = entry.data;
        loadBitmap(imageByte, holder.mNetworkImageView,imageURL);
    }else{
        holder.mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(imageURL, mImageLoader);
    }*/

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(mIssueList != null){
        return mIssueList.size();           
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

public List<Issue> getIssueList() {
    return mIssueList;
}

}
```

Comment: `NetworkImageView` does use 2 levels of cache : memory cache created by developer and disk cache created by Volley itself. Image is first checked in memory cache, then disk cache, if not found then only network request is placed. So nothing extra need to be done to make it work in offline mode. Can you share your code to see if there is any issue in it?

Comment: @ManishMulimani many thanks for your help, I have updated my question. the problem is when I close my app and open it again just placeholder of images are shown, the texts below the image all of them are loaded correctly but the image dose not.Again thanks.

Comment: ImageLoader already have `isCached(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)`, if the cache checked there not the same as getRequestQueue().getCache(), then reimplement `ImageLoader` add a Context memeber, and check the cached images using the first line in your question. src code ImageLoader: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java

Comment: `DiskBasedCache` default maximum cache size is 5MB. As you are using very high resolution images (3000x2500 i.e. 7.5MB), you can increase the cache size.  Use `DiskBasedCache(File rootDirectory, int maxCacheSizeInBytes)` constructor to specify the disk size i.e. `DiskBasedCache(cacheDir, 20 * 1024 * 1024)` for 20MB cache. Let me know whether it helps.

Comment: @ManishMulimani I have already set it like `/** Default maximum disk usage in bytes.*/private static final int DEFAULT_DISK_USAGE_BYTES = 20 * 1024 * 1024;`

Comment: With the `Entry` instance you explicitly get from cache, can you check whether it is expired using `entry.expired()` and whether refresh is needed using `entry.refreshNeeded()`? In case of `NetworkImageView`, if entry is expired then network request is placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line in BasicNetwork class

```
if (!ConnectivityUtils.isNetworkEnabled(CardApplication.getContext()) && request instanceof ImageRequest) {
            VolleyLog.e("Cached response", "No Network Connectivity for Url=", request.getUrl());
            return new NetworkResponse(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED,
                    request.getCacheEntry().data, responseHeaders, true);
        }
```

and for data request expiry you can change the Cached.Entry using using own HttpHeaderParser

Here is [Link](http://mobilewebwizard.in/2015/01/offline-caching-with-volley-using-cache-controlled-header/) which explain thing in detail

Comment: http://mobilewebwizard.in/2015/01/offline-caching-with-volley-using-cache-controlled-header/

Comment: You welcome Actually You should not cache Data Request , thats why I have added request instanceof ImageRequest ,

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use Volley/retrofit with [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
/[Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), picture loader libs have done a great job in loading and caching images indeed.

They handle everything with a single line of code by default:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Also you can animate, resize your images and add placeholder while they loading.

Comment: Thanks(+1) @Pedram I already knew all of them but for now I do not want to use other library and also my images are 3000*2500 and I think those libraries get into trouble with this resolution:-)

Comment: I think you would need two version of your images, one as thumbnail for showing in 'ListView' and one in original size, I suggest generate thumbnail of your images and load them with Picasso for instance, and download the real size images with volley as you prefer and cache them with DiskLruCache https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache, I looked at Volley's DiskBasedCache source but didn't find it interesting, read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916478/performance-issue-with-volleys-diskbasedcache Good luck

Comment: @mmlooloo I find this by the way give it a shot http://stackoverflow.com/a/26565940/2970351

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you restart your app in offline, the last thing you can rely on just the Disk Cache(i.e. **DiskBasedCache**). Volley's local cache consist of network data and the response headers. But in this situation, we just need to focusing on the `Cache-Control` header. For instance, if the server-side return that header is "Cache-Control: max-age=604800", that's tell Volley to cache the response resource for 604800 seconds( source at [HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java) ). Then next time we retrieving the same url's data would checking if exceeded the cache expire time, finally decide retrieve from network or local.

Follow your describe, I suppose your server-side deliver you a value like `Cache-Control:must-revalidate|proxy-revalidate|no-cache|no-store`, that's why you can't reuse the last retrieved data when you were in offline.

Right now there is question came : once we can manipulate the cache expire time, we'll be capable of increase that time to a large enough value so we can ensure us use that data in offline.

Unfortunately, Volley does not support us to do this. So if you can make the server-side to delivering a viable **max-age** for this?

If not, I'd suggest you to change to another library which fulfill this desired. and there actually have one can be your friend, is [Netroid](https://github.com/vince-styling/Netroid). It's based on Volley and offered a few improvements, that won't make you change your current code very much. With it, control the expire time would be far easier, and more features would be come with.

```
mImageLoader = new SelfImageLoader(mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache) {
    @Override
    public void makeRequest(ImageRequest request) {
        // you can manipulate the cache expire time with one line code.
        request.setCacheExpireTime(TimeUnit.DAYS, 10);

        // you can even according to the different request to
        // set up the corresponding expire time.
        if (request.getUrl().contains("/for_one_day/")) {
            request.setCacheExpireTime(TimeUnit.DAYS, 1);
        } else {
            request.setCacheExpireTime(TimeUnit.DAYS, 10);
        }
    }
};
```

the full code was on the project's sample module, i hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but I think you have not read my question carefully, the data is already in my `disckcache` because I can fetch the images by `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entry.data, 0, entry.data.length);`

Comment: oh, yes, i'm so sorry for this, wish you gain the rightful answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hello @mmlooloo I have created a project which use `DiskLRUCache` and `Volley`. Here's the link of my repository [DiskLRUCache using Volley](https://github.com/androidcodehunter/AndroidVolleyWithDIskCache). Hope it will helps you to show saved image. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help(+1) but Volley already cached my images I just want to make it fetch those from **its** DiskLRUCache. I am using `NetworkImageView` which handles all of my issues for listview and decoding and ... but it dose not work when I am offline.

Comment: Volley use only memory cache. So we need to implement our own DiskLRU cache if we want to show it offline. Check my solution code  .

Comment: No it is not, it has `DiskLRU` check the source code:-)

Comment: As far I know Volley dosn't support DiskCache. Okay I will check the source of Volley.

Comment: @Sharif you are mistaken. Volley caches every response on the disk. It caches images on the memory you cache you provide the ImageLoader. And by the way - providing a disk cache to the `ImageLoader` class like you do in your project is a mistake. You're supposed to provide a memory cache. You are slowing down your app and creating disk redundancies as Volley already caches every response on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search internet for "android how to check internet connectivity"
2. implement that and check it in your cache implementation (like `LruCache`).
   `if(networkAvailable()){ getFromNetwork()} else { getFromCache()}`

logic is ok? then just try.
It seems your cache impl class is `LruBitmapCache`.

then how about check connectivity in that class?

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
  if(networkAvailable()/* this is your impl */){
    // dont use cache
    return null;
  }
  return getFromCache();  // or something like that;
}
```

Comment: You don't use cache just because your internet isn't on... Cache is to speed up performance and reduce slow network calls where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would benefit if the memory cache provided to the `ImageLoader` class that's used by your `NetworkImageView` will be persisted between app runs, without losing the fact that it's a **memory** cache.

That memory cache keeps the correctly sized bitmap in normal operation - which you would like available even if the network goes down.

So here's an idea: every time you're app is closed, persist on file the images from the cache. The next time you load your app, when you create the memory cache - check for a persisted version on the disk, and if it's available - populate the memory cache from the disk.

There are several approaches you can take to decide when to persist an image and when to delete it.

Here's one approach: create a hybrid memory / disk cache. It would work exactly the same as your memory cache works now with the following differences:

1. Every time `putBitmap()` is called, along with your normal operation, save an encoded version of the bitmap to the disk in a background thread / `AsyncTask`.
2. Every time a bitmap is removed from the cache (I'm assuming you have some sort of space constraint on the cache), delete that file from the disk on a background thread / `AsyncTask`.
3. Create a "loadFromDisk" task, to be performed in the background every time a memory cache is created (once per app run) to populate your memory cache with the available images from the disk.

You can't avoid decoding the bitmaps, however you can cut the size and having to deal with resizing large bitmaps.

Does this help you?

Comment: "Does this help you?" no because you have not read my question carefully, Volley uses **DiskLRUCache** and memory cache. My data is there in **DiskLRUCache**.

Comment: I did read your question. You wrote that images saved on the disk cache or too large and you don't want to go to the trouble of decoding and resizing them. I suggested a way for you to skip the resizing part. I'm sorry to say that the only way to save a bitmap is by encoding it - so decoding is something you can't escape if you want persistency. Perhaps you didn't understand my answer.

Comment: may be I commented badly but I do not want to decode it myself I want to make volley decode that.